# Android Facebook login dialog opens without any styling

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, cordova, facebook-android-sdk, cordova-2.0.0

I am using the Cordova official Facebook plugin and run into a weird issue...
The login process, which previously worked just fine for me, is now open in some native Android "black-screen" view without any styling.

[image]

The functionality works just fine - the authentication process succeeds, so there is a consistent connection with Facebook. The thing is, I am expecting a Facebook view instead of only the text content without any styling. Here is an example with Facebook native Hackbook app:

[image]

1. Tried running on two different devices - the issue remains.
2. Tried with cordova 2.2.0, then started a fresh project with 2.5.0 - the issue remains.

Please advice.

**UPDATE:**

Well, I have spent too much time on this issue, and it seems like this is the new Facebook SDK for Android.

I really wish I am wrong here, but here are examples from Facebook's flow for Android:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/

Also - when checking the other sample apps in the SDK, all of them behave the same. The only one that shows a Facebook page is the Hackbook, and by it might be because this app is implemented with the old API (version 2):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

Hackbook: another sample app demonstrating a selection of Graph API calls. Note that this sample is untouched from v2.0 of the SDK, and demonsrates the SDK's backward-compatibility.

**UPDATE 2:**

Ok, digging a bit more into it, it seems that there is no iframe involved here, the screen can be changed as you wish with a regular android activity theme added to the activity.

Here is an example of adding one of Androids default themes to the androidMenifest.xml (you can of course create your own Faceboke like theme ):

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
      android:label="@string/facebook_login" />
```